# Array to the string without commas and one letter next to the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I'm using join("") to turn it to the string, but when I console.log it one letter is under the other. How can I change that to make letters next to eachother?

```
var array = [d,o,g];
var array2 = array.join("");
console.log(array2);
```

result:

```
d
o
g
```

and I want:

```
dog
```

Comment: Note that `[d,o,g]` is not the same as `['d', 'o', 'g']`, without quotes those are variable names (or functions), I recommend you use some linter when coding

Comment: var array = ["d","o","g"];

Comment: right, op is speaking of letters, not from variables.

Comment: The only way your code would do what you claim it is doing is if `d`, `o`, and `g` are variables, and they equal `'d\n'`, `'o\n'`, and `'g\n'`, respectively.

Comment: @forgivenson would work but very twisted :)

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Yup. I was just trying to explain what the OP is actually doing, because the code as written will produce errors. And even if the OP meant to say `var array = ['d','o','g']`, that wouldn't produce the output given.

Comment: @forgivenson I know this is just an example to explain the output, it may contain `\n` because it comes from some config file !?

Answer (score 2):

It works this way, you have.

```js
var array = ['d','o','g'];
var array2 = array.join("");
console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Put letters inside quote :

```
var array = ['d','o','g'];

var array2 = array.join("");

console.log(array2);
```